# SAG Web Methods - Soap Web Service - URL Alias

Tags: webmethods

We have SAG Webmethods implementation being used as an API Gateway in our project. We do not have much expertise in WebMethods. Based on a document received from the team which was maintaining this gateway implementation we are trying to build a custom gateway solution using open source software.

There is a soap web service which is being accessed by clients using /soap URL but based on looking at the web service implementation with WebMethods, we can see that the soap web service end point is of the pattern /ws/**.

Any idea where can we check to find how the mapping is happening from incoming url /soap to actual soap webservice end point /ws/**? We checked under "Settings > URL Aliases" of Web Methods Integration Server but there is no url alias set for this mapping.

Could you please help provide some pointers on where such a configuration could be set up for this redirection?

Regards,
Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood the issue the right way, this configuration is done as a part of webMethods code only. you need to open the wM packages in `SoftwareAG Designer` and in the Service Development  perspective of Designer ,Connect to the `Integration Server` with those packages and have a look at the contents. You need to find something called WSD. if you right click and say property you will see the Element Type as :`Web Service Descriptor`.Open the WSD and on the right side you can see properties window which can have properties like `WSDL URL /Source URI`. this is where this /ws/ Config is done. Any requests hitting this URL will be handled by the associated WSD defined.

There is also an option to add an alias here in

> admin Console--->Settings-->WebService--->Create provider /Web Service
>   endpoint Alias

.